# How should i close my express server in git bash terminal

Tags: express, git-bash

I start my express server by `npm run start` in git bash terminal. I have two ways for closing running server - press `Ctrl+C` and close terminal window.

First way works awesome. Express server closing connection and ends it's work.

Second way is closing only terminal window but server is still working. If I open terminal again and make `npm run start` I'll get error like `server on this port already works`. Finally kill server can only restart computer.

Here is my code of express server:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import router from './router';
import { EXPRESS_DEVSERVER_PORT } from '../src/const/api-const';

const port = EXPRESS_DEVSERVER_PORT;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    })
);

router(app);

const server = app.listen(port, (error?: Error) => {
    if (error) return console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', closeMockServerHandler);
process.on('SIGINT', closeMockServerHandler);

function closeMockServerHandler() {
  console.log('Closing server....');
  server.close(() => {
      process.exit();
  });
  console.log('Server successfully closed');
};
```

Please help, is there anyway of correctly closing express server together closing terminal window?

Comment: Hmm I don't know. This also happen for me. I think git bash doesn't kill the process when its window is closed.

Comment: You can kill the process from the command line or process manager.

Comment: @kennarddh, you are right. I've checked it. After killing git bash terminal in VS Code express server killing too. But closing separate git bash window not killing server.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I'd like to kill the process at the same time as closing the terminal window without additional actions.

Comment: If you want to use shortcut. You can combine 2 shortcuts. `Ctrl + C` to kill and `Ctrl + D` to logout and close the window.